# How to rename df columns without temporarily storing the column list into a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am extracting and loading a Snowflake table into a PySpark DataFrame, and I want to rename its columns.
Right now, this is being done storing the loaded dataframe into a variable and then accessing the column list:

```py
calculated_signal_df = (
    spark.read.format("snowflake")
    .options(**sfOptions)
    .option("query", "select * from iot.calculated_signal")
    .load()
)
calculated_signal_df = calculated_signal_df.toDF(*[c.lower() for c in calculated_signal_df.columns])
```

I was actually wondering whether is possible to skip the intermediate passage and piping `toDF()` method directly after `load()`. My first doubt would be how to get hold of the column list.

The second approach that comes to my mind is to defining original and desired column names beforehand and then use them, but I was trying not to create variables at all.

Is this possible in Pandas and/or Python? (I assume what works for Pandas dataframes, works somehow for PySpark dataframes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [withColumnRenamed](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-withcolumnrenamed). Also, there are few alternatives methods if you want to perform any operation on columns [Check here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-withcolumn).
[Here](https://github.com/Evergreenies/data_engineering_pyspark/blob/main/pyspark_scripts/india_covid_19_analysis.ipynb), you can find some examples.